# mysql order based on concat list

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

- products
- attributes

products.product_attributes contains a concat list of all the attribute identifiers related to this product. But my problem is with the ordering, the concat list contains all of the identifers in a manually specified order, but this has no effect on the order of the results.

How can I use a concat list to identify the order?

Query example:

```
SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE attribute_id IN(products.product_attributes)
```

Comment: How is a join going to solve my issue of ordering? And how is this "off-topic" and recieve a down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Raymond Nijland, less hacky solution:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT attributes.* FROM attributes, products 
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET(attribute_id, product_attributes) IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: How come not the best design? I didn't want to create an extra table so thought this is the only way to be able to use the IN() easily. I only want to store the relational data for 1-many?

Comment: you cannot use IN with a string field.

Comment: Thanks guys this is work perfect, too many mysql functions I dont know about and need to read up on the rare ones